# Laravel Blade How to print out uri with @show action

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my view, I want to print a controller uri like this `ShopController@show`.

set the var `$controller = 'ShopControll';`

**in the view:**

```
action($controller.'@show',$id)
```

**but there are some error occured:**

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 603:
Action App\Http\Controllers\ShopController<?php echo $__env->yieldSection(); ?> not defined.
```

**if like this:**

```
action('ShopController@show',$id)
```

**it works, output is:**

```
http://example.com/show/1
```

So, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@show is a blade directive, blade parse it you want to show this as section please check here example

```
@section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
@show
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#template-inheritance

you can modify you method like this

```
action($controller,'show',$id)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel >= 5.3 you can use a combination with [`@php @endphp`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#php):

```
@php 
    echo @action($controller.'@show', ['id' => $id]) 
@endphp
```

For earlier versions, I think (tested only on **5.3** *again*), this should work too:

```
{{ @action($controller.'@show', ['id' => $id])}}
```